# Facebook conversion without pixel

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need an alternative way to register a conversion with facebook. I cannot do it with javascript, as conversions may occur a couple of days after lead registration on websites I do not control. I see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/pixel-with-ads/conversion-tracking) that I can register a conversion through an API call, but it's pixel ID based and I want to also tell facebook which visitor (click ID) actually converted. Is there a way of doing this?